# created a HTML command in a java class method and imported it to JSP but it was not working

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I created a dynamic project and in eclipse and then created a method insert and then added that to jsp and its working then I tried to create a read method and after and added everything in it and imported it to jsp but the HTML commands just printed to the console not created a table

this my Item.java class read  item method

```
public String readItems() {
        
        String output = "";
        
        try {
            Connection con = connect();
            
            if (con == null) {
                
                return "Error While connecting  to the  database  for reading ";
            }
            //preapre the html table to be displayed
            
            output = "<table boder= '1'><tr><th>Item Code</th>"
                    +"<th>Item Name</th><th>Item Price</th>"
                    + "<th>Item Description</th>"
                    + "<th>Update</th><th>Remove</th></tr>";
            
            String query = "select * from item";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            
            // iterate through the rows in the result set
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                
                String itemID = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("itemID"));
                String itemCode = rs.getString("itemCode");
                String itemName = rs.getString("itemName");
                String itemPrice = Double.toString(rs.getDouble("itemPrice"));
                String itemDesc = rs.getString("itemDesc");
                
                // Add a row into the html table
                output += "<tr><td>" + itemCode + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + itemName + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + itemPrice + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + itemDesc + "</td>";
                // buttons
                output += "<td><input name='btnUpdate' "
                + " type='button' value='Update'></td>"
                + "<td><form method='post' action='items.jsp'>"
                + "<input name='btnRemove' "
                + " type='submit' value='Remove'>"
                + "<input name='itemID' type='hidden' "
                + " value='" + itemID + "'>" + "</form></td></tr>";
            }
            con.close();
            // Complete the html table
            
            output += "</table>";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        output = "Error while reading the items.";
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return output;
    }
```

then I imported it to jsp

```
    <%
    Item itemObj = new Item();
    System.out.print(itemObj.readItems());
%>
```

and the output is

> > Successfully connectedItem CodeItem NameItem PriceItem DescriptionUpdateRemoveKdsjame200.0nice onekljames200.0nice<input name='bt.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the result from `itemObj.readItems()` through the `out` JspWriter object, not to `System.out`, if you want it to be part of the content sent to the client.

Comment: You are printing to the system console, not to the Writer for sending content to the browser.

Comment: yes simple thing bro i changed it and its working can I have an upvote for the reputation